# Problems plotting user data in achartengine with data which is a changeable value from a table

Tags: java, android, graph, charts, achartengine

I'm using achartengine to plot a graph in my app. I declare points in a table in `table.xml` which is connected to `Table.java`. Now should my graph get this points and use them. My graph is coded in `Graph.java` and gets called through `Graphdisplay.java`.

**EDIT2:** I changed the code a bit. First of all I added the code from `Graphdisplay.java` into the onCreate method of `Graph.java` and deleted `Graphdisplay.java`.

Second I added some get and set methods like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871052/android-how-to-make-plot-with-user-data) in the first answer in `Graph.java` and get the data from `Table.java` in the onCreate method.

Third I put the get method in the GraphicalView

`Graph.java:`

```
public class Graph extends Activity{

//only for x1 for now
public double ds_x1;
public Double getX1(){return this.ds_x1;}
public void setX1(Double ds_x1){this.ds_x1=ds_x1;}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph);

    //getting the data from Table.java
    ds_x1 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("s_x1");

    Graph line = new Graph();
    final GraphicalView gView = line.getView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    layout.addView(gView);

}

public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {

    Double d_x1 = getX1();

    ArrayList<Double> xList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double x1 = d_x1;
    xList.add(x1);
    double x2 = 2;
    xList.add(x2);
    double x3 = 3;
    xList.add(x3);

    ArrayList<Double> yList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double y1 = 1;
    yList.add(y1);
    double y2 = 2;
    yList.add(y2);
    double y3 = 3;
    yList.add(y3);

    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("List");
    for (int i = 0; i < xList.size(); i++) {
        series.add(i, xList.get(i), yList.get(i));
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);
    } 
}
```

`Table.java:` Now Double not Strings

```
 EditText x1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.x1);
 EditText x2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.x2);
 EditText x3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.x3);
 EditText y1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y1);
 EditText y2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y2);
 EditText y3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y3);

 Button b_continue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_continue);
    b_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Double s_x1 = Double.parseDouble(x1.getText().toString());
            Double s_x2 = Double.parseDouble(x2.getText().toString());
            Double s_x3 = Double.parseDouble(x3.getText().toString());
            Double s_y1 = Double.parseDouble(y1.getText().toString());
            Double s_y2 = Double.parseDouble(y2.getText().toString());
            Double s_y3 = Double.parseDouble(y3.getText().toString());

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Graph.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("s_x1", s_x1);
            myIntent.putExtra("s_x2", s_x2);
            myIntent.putExtra("s_x3", s_x3);
            myIntent.putExtra("s_y1", s_y1);
            myIntent.putExtra("s_y2", s_y2);
            myIntent.putExtra("s_y3", s_y3);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

**Logcat:**

```
  08-29 14:31:00.720  17322-17322/test.com.myApp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{test.com.myApp/test.com.myApp.Graph}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at test.com.myApp.Graph.getView(Graph.java:96)
        at test.com.myApp.Graph.onCreate(Graph.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Problem:** When clicking on the button to get to the graph the app crashes instead of showing the graph with the values! I figured out that the problem is that it isn't a defined value like `double double = 5.0`. aChartEngine has got problems with the values wich are getting entered in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a method to set "double extras" to your intent:
Intent android.content.Intent.putExtra(String name, double value)

and a method to get double extras:
double android.content.Intent.getDoubleExtra(String name, double defaultValue)

so you don't need to parse the strings...

But yeah, in general that's the right approach. Or do you have a specific problem with it?

EDIT:
use this instead of valueOf:

double y2 = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("s_y2"))

EDIT2, try:

```
 Button b_continue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_continue);
 b_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String s_x1 = x1.getText().toString();
        String s_x2 = x2.getText().toString();
        String s_x3 = x3.getText().toString();
        String s_y1 = y1.getText().toString();
        String s_y2 = y2.getText().toString();
        String s_y3 = y3.getText().toString();

        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Graph.class);
        myIntent2.putExtra("s_x1", s_x1);
        myIntent2.putExtra("s_x2", s_x2);
        myIntent2.putExtra("s_x3", s_x3);
        myIntent2.putExtra("s_y1", s_y1);
        myIntent2.putExtra("s_y2", s_y2);
        myIntent2.putExtra("s_y3", s_y3);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Graphdisplay.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: ah sorry, i see you're getting the values from edit texts, so you need to parse them anyway...

Comment: Instead of valueOf you should use something like double y2 = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("s_y2"))

Comment: OK, I'm sorry again, there is actually a method valueOf(String) so that was fine too.....
But what's the problem actually??? Is your code not working? And what's happening instead?

Comment: You need to tell us what exactly the problem is. When/Where is the app crashing and with what error message? Look into the logcat and copy the error message and post it here please...
One idea: you seem to read the strings from the EditTexts too early. you should put the lines
"String s_x1 = x1.getText().toString();"
into the onClick method. The way it is now, all the strings are most probably empty which might cause the crash...

Comment: **logcat added** -just filling characters-

Comment: ok, I just noticed that you do something strange in Graph. You should really read https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html